# Python. Как ввести много значений в input() и обработать их

Tags: python, парсер, input

Есть программа для парсинга страниц игр в Steam. Правда в тудв можно ввести только одну старницу. Как можно ввести сразу не одну а много ссылок. И получить по всем результат.
Вот :
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот код:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import os

HEADERS = {'user-agent': '...', 'accept': '*/*'}

def get_html(url, params=None):
    r = requests.get(url, headers=HEADERS, params=params)
    return r

def get_content(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    items = soup.find_all('div', class_='page_content_ctn')

    something = []
    for item in items:
    
        something.append({
            'name': item.find('div', class_='apphub_AppName').get_text(strip=True),
            'cost': item.find('div', class_='game_purchase_price price').get_text(strip=True),
    
        })
    print(something)

def parse():
    URL = input('URL: ')
    URL = URL.strip()

    html = get_html(URL)

    if html.status_code == 200:
        something = get_content(html.text)
    else:
        print('Error')

parse()
```

Спасибо

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: [Чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers), проголосуйте за ответ и отметьте его [галочкой](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) как решение.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На вход вводится url-ы через пробел. Далее разбить на список. И обработать все элементы списка.
По идее должно получиться как то так:

```
def parse():
    URL = input('URL: ')
    urllist = URL.split(" ") # получаем список url

    for i in urlist: # Выполняем код для каждого элемента в списке
        html = get_html(i.strip())

        if html.status_code == 200:
            something = get_content(html.text)
        else:
            print('Error')
```

2 Вариант:

```py
def parse():
    URL = []
    print("URL: ", end='')
    while True: # запрашиваем ввод в бесконечном цикле
        data = input()
        if data == "": # пока не получим пустую строку
            break
        URL.append(data) # Полученные данные добавим в список URL
        
    for i in URL:
        html = get_html(i.strip())

        if html.status_code == 200:
            something = get_content(html.text)
        else:
            print('Error')
```

Comment: Спасибо. А можно ссылки поставить не через пробел. А как на последнем изображении.

Comment: В текущем вариант если Вы нажмете enter ввод завершится... Тогда лучше в цикле и получать данные из ввода. Через пару мин дополню немного ответ.

Comment: Огромное спасибо, теперь все работает. В 1 варианте пропущена буква в for i in urlist: нужно for i in urllist: